# Getting unique values from loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, uniq, do-loops

I've got it so that I have a list of the unique patients a clinician is having a conversation with.  I can call up details about the patients but I can't call up anything to do with the associated comment.

### app\views\comments\index.html.erb

```
    <% @comments.map(&:patient).uniq.each_with_index do |comment, index| %>
      <div class="profile-post color-one">
          <span class="profile-post-numb"><%= index+1 %></span>
          <div class="profile-post-in">
              <h3 class="heading-xs"><a><%= link_to "#{comment.first_name} #{comment.last_name}", comment_path(comment) %></a></h3>
              <p><%= comment.diagnosis %><i class="pull-right"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_comment_path(comment) %> <%= link_to "Delete", comment_path(comment), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete'} %></i></p>
          </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

The link_to are also broken since they are supposed to direct to a comment page but are passing patient.id instead of comment.id.

### comments_conrtoller.rb

```
def index
 @comments = current_clinician.comments
end
```

### comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :clinician
 belongs_to :patient
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@comments.map(&:patient)` gives objects which are of class `Patient`, and that is why the links are passing `patient_id` instead of `comment_id`.

You should be using `group` instead of `map` here.

Something along the lines of `@comments.group(:patient)..` ; the loop syntax has to be changed to work with the output from this scope.

See http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group for more details about how `group` works.

Comment: I'm still getting:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: patient: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  GROUP BY patient.

I've changed the view to:
`code`<% @comments.group(:patient).each_with_index do |comment, index| %>`code`

and the controller to:
`code`def index
 @comments = Comment.all
end`code`

For now until I get it working.  I think I can use 'having' to get it to just show ones from the current user

Comment: `@comments.group(:patient_id)...` . I would suggest playing with this within the console before figuring out the correct looping construct to use.

Comment: The best way ended up being:

   '<% @comments.group(:patient_id).each_with_index do |comment, index| %>'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi again Prakash - your suggestion worked great locally but gave my a GroupingError when I pushed to heroku.
**PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "comments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**
If you have any advice for this it would be much appreciated